# How to take a sum of a sum in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following data that I need to get a sum of a sum.

| Item_Number | Work_Order_Number | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X-1 | 11 | 10 |
| X-1 | 11 | 10 |
| X-1 | 11 | 10 |
| X-1 | 121 | 15 |
| X-1 | 121 | 15 |
| X-1 | 121 | 15 |
| X-1 | 131 | 20 |
| X-1 | 131 | 20 |
| X-1 | 131 | 20 |

The problem with this data is the repetition.

I used the following code to clean it up a bit.

```
SELECT 
    Item_Number,
    Work_Order_Number,
    SUM(Qty) AS QTY,
    COUNT(Work_Order_ID) AS Count
FROM table
WHERE Item_Number = 'X-1' 
GROUP BY Item_Number, Work_Order_Number
```

To get the following:

| Item_Number | Work_Order_Number | QTY | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X-1 | 11 | 30 | 3 |
| X-1 | 121 | 45 | 3 |
| X-1 | 131 | 60 | 3 |

How can I change to code to get the following:

| Item_Number | Total_Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| X-1 | 45 |

I have tried using this:

```
SELECT 
    Item_Number,
    Work_Order_Number,
    SUM(Qty) AS QTY,
    COUNT(Work_Order_ID) AS Count
    SUM(SUM(Qty)/COUNT(Work_Order_ID)) AS Total_Quantity
FROM table1
WHERE Item_Number = 'X-1' 
GROUP BY Item_Number
```

Comment: looks like you want to get `SUM(Qty)/COUNT(DISTINCT Work_Order_ID) ...  GROUP BY Item_Number`

Comment: Well...that was simple. I made this too difficult

Comment: What's your really expected result?

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you want to get total of a column, if so here is the query.

```
SELECT SUM(Qty) AS totalQuantiy FROM table1;
```

If data type is Varchar use COUNT function.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you want the total average quantity.

> ```
> SELECT 
>   Item_Number
> , SUM(AverageQuantity) AS Total_Quantity
> FROM
> (
>   SELECT 
>     Item_Number
>   , Work_Order_Number
>   , AVG(Qty) AS AverageQuantity
>   FROM table1
>   WHERE Item_Number = 'X-1' 
>   GROUP BY Item_Number, Work_Order_Number
> ) q
> GROUP BY Item_Number
> ```

| Item_Number | Total_Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| X-1 | 45.0000 |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9dd19e9d6628fe13af765540c01f4bfe)*

Comment: Is there a way I can group by year? I tried adding YEAR(Date_Issued) and I get an ERROR say they can't find 'Date_Issued'.

Comment: Yes, but put `YEAR(Date_Issued)` in the group by of the sub-query, not the name.  Then in the other group by you can use the name.

Comment: What do you mean by "name"? Do I put YEAR(Date_Issued) in SELECT?

Comment: Could you edit your post and add Year(Date_Issued)? I can't get seem to get this to work. I keep getting error code 1054

Comment: I've changed the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Item_Number,
       SUM(QTY) / COUNT(Item_Number) AS Total_Quantity
FROM
  (SELECT 
      Item_Number,
      SUM(Qty) AS QTY
  FROM table
  WHERE Item_Number = 'X-1' 
  GROUP BY Item_Number, Work_Order_Number) T
GROUP BY Item_Number
```